# how can a userscript get notified about ajax-driven changes on the page?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

Given items on a webpage that get changed by AJAX calls over time, how can a userscript get notified about those changes, whenever they occur?

Imagine the Facebook newsfeed.  It has 12 items in it when you load the page.  Those items are wrapped in `<li>` tags contained within a `<ul>`.  As you scroll the page down, new `<li>` chunks of data load into that `<ul>`.

I'm wondering how a userscript could be notified of such a change.

One idea is to constantly query that `<ul>`, counting its items, and watching to see if that number gets bigger.  Possible, but to catch the change right when it happens it might have to run so often that it's too expensive.

Another idea would be to figure out what scroll position triggers the loading, and to watch for such a change.  Less expensive, but very specific.

**I'm wondering if there's a third option.**  Something that would notify me of the change, whenever it happens.  I'm not just interested in the feed, but in this concept more generally.  Given items on a page that get changed by AJAX calls, how can a userscript get notified about those changes?

Comment: Are you using Firefox, Chrome, or both?

Comment: both. safari would be great too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hijack the send method

```
var oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(){
    // do what you need; then send the request
    oldSend.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the DOMSubtreeModified event.

This works in firefox chrome and IE >= 9, if your scripting on facebook im guessing its for a greasemonkey/chrome extension?  if that is the case this should be okay.

This event is fired on a node when ever a child node is added removed or changed

You can use it with

```
.addEventListener ("DOMSubtreeModified", handler, useCapture);
```

but I don't think it works with attachEvent.

Here's some more info on it.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php

Comment: This is a bad suggestion.  Mutation events are flaky, resource intensive, and are now deprecated.  `DOMSubtreeModified`, etc. is not recommended and support for such events will be withdrawn in future versions of the browsers.

Comment: Good to know, I haven't really used them, they were they only solution I could come up with that did not involve saving and comparing values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the Ajax calls that are updating the pages contents? Generally the better approach is to attach a call back to the actual Ajax call.

If the request are being made with Jquery use $.ajaxComplete() or $.ajaxSuccess() to trigger your code.  These will fire any time a request completes so when this happens you can check if the content has changed without it being to expensive.

```
$.ajaxSuccess(function() { //check for update and do something });
```

Comment: This should be a comment, you're asking a question about the question. OP wants to script Facebook

Comment: I had thought facebook was an example, You are right, it should have been a comment, I have updated to include a valid answer

Comment: i am specifically interested in FB, just not only the feed.  ticker, etc is also of interest.